# i create my own npm package and publish it but when i trying to use it, it gives me an error

Tags: reactjs, npm, package, npm-install

I create reactjs component and make it publish on npm . i install it in my another project and now when i try to import it giving full path such as

```
import RippleIcon from '../node_modules/rippleicon/src/RippleIcon';
```

it gives me an error that

```
./node_modules/rippleicon/src/RippleIcon.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   render() {
|     return (
|         <i className={this.props.icon+" RippleIcon"}/>
|     );
|   }
```

rippleicon is my npm package name, and i create my package on create-react-app. any suggestions are welcome. thank you.

this is my package.json

```
{
 "name": "packagetesting",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
   "react": "^16.3.2",
   "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
   "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
   "rippleicon": "^0.1.1"
},
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a node package and link it to a project is relatively easy. Assuming you will have `mypackage` and `myproject` on the same path, try with this steps:

**1.- Package**

```
$ mkdir mypackage
$ cd mypackage/
$ npm init -y
$ echo "exports.myfunc = function() { console.log(\"Hello\"); }" > index.js
$ cd ..
```

Its `package.json` content will be:

```
{
  "name": "mypackage",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**2.- Project**

```
$ mkdir myproject
$ cd myproject/
$ npm init -y
$ npm install "file:../mypackage" --save
$ echo "var mp = require('mypackage'); mp.myfunc();" > index.js
$ node index.js
```

You will see that "Hello" is printed. Its `package.json` content will be:

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "mypackage": "file:../mypackage"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, there are some: 1- "rippleicon": "file:local/path/to/package", 2- "main": "src/index.js", 3- import RippleIcon from 'ripleicon', etc. I don't know your project details, but you can figure out what's incorrect.

Comment: Ok what i did is, i make a react component and then npm run build and publish it to the npm package, now i make another project and install that package via npm. So when i import it, it gives me an error that you may need an appropriate loader for this type of file.

Comment: I understand, but you are making mistakes on configuration and import your local package.

Comment: I have to import it from full path otherwise its giving me module not find error. I google it but they were mentioning about webpack file which i don't know what for.

Comment: You can check my code on Github.com/amitruls1/rippleicon.git

Comment: Yo can check my answer and first understand the idea of import a package, then apply to your project. Also, your repo results in 404 error.